# Python/Pygame script not responding when closed, while Renoise is open

Tags: python, pygame, freeze, osc

I'm writing a Python script using Pygame and OSC that will allow me to control the music tracker software Renoise (version 3.0.0) by doing things in a Pygame (1.9.1) environment and sending messages to the software via OSC. If you're wondering, the purpose of this script is for live performance and generative music creation. I'm having a pretty annoying issue, however: when I try to close the Pygame window, it just hangs - doesn't even respond to Control+C - but this only happens if Renoise is open, or has been opened at least once during the session. If I reboot and run the script without opening Renoise, it works as intended. What could possibly be the issue here?

I'm using Python version 2.7.6, Pygame version 1.9.1, and Renoise version 3.0.0. This is all running on an Xubuntu 14.04 laptop.

Code for my main script (the imported OSC module is simply OSC.py available in many places [on the internet](https://gitorious.org/pyosc/devel/source/633c0112318a3519314aa798a552a092566c73c1%3aOSC.py)):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import pygame
import OSC
from pygame.locals import *

class Pot:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.clk = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (1600, 900) )
        self.fillColor = pygame.Color(255,255,255)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame OSC Test")

        self.client = OSC.OSCClient()
        self.client.connect( (ip, port) )

    def oscsend(self, addr, *data):
        msg = OSC.OSCMessage()
        msg.setAddress("/renoise" + str(addr))
        for d in data:
            msg.append(d)
        try:
            self.client.send(msg)
        except OSC.OSCClientError, err:
            print err

    def tick(self):
        # clear the screen
        self.screen.fill(self.fillColor)

        #TODO: other drawing stuff here

        # process events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.client.close()
                del(self.client)
                return False

        pygame.display.update()
        self.clk.tick(10)

        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p,f = pygame.init()
    print "Num modules passed:", p
    print "Num modules failed:", f

    pot = Pot("localhost", 8000)

    running = True
    while running:
        running = pot.tick()

    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix my problem by making sure `pygame.mixer` wasn't initialized. I assume it was causing some problems with Renoise by them both using the sound hardware at the same time.

To only initialize certain modules of pygame, just call their initialization methods individually. For instance, `pygame.display.init()` will initialize the Display module. Calling `pygame.init()` is simply a shortcut to initializing all the currently loaded modules. Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: That's really good to know! I also use PyGame often for "non-game" applications (it just offers a few things you can't find elsewhere that elaborated). And knowing this can probably prevent a bunch of issues in the future. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Edited version after a closer look: You are returning False when the programme is quitted. But the variable "running" still remains true! Your loop is still going about his business and happily looping there...

I'd change it this way:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        self.client.close()
        del(self.client)
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

2nd option:

```
return False
```

Change this part that "running" is set to false. i'd go with the first option though.

If that doesn't solve the problem, please let me know, that would be an interesting issue to have a closer look at.

Comment: Haha, thanks for catching that but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. Program is still behaving as before.

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I see, if I have a closer look at the issue tomorrow. I'd have to get Renoise somewhere - is it freeware? Otherwise I can't really try :/

Comment: Thanks Patric, but I managed to figure out my issue on my own. See my answer to this post.